How to plot a map in superset
I am trying to plot a map in superset from a dataset which contains these columns:
x_id, longitude, latitude.
I am using deck.gl Scatterplot.
I want a result like this one:
enter image description here
But what I got is that:
enter image description here
Can you please help on how can I fix that?
I have another question: when I move the mouse over the map , I see longitude and latitude information. I would like to display x_id instead. How can I achieve this?
I want to get a result like this one:
enter image description here

To have access to your map, you need to get mapbox API keys, then update your superset_config.py with your mapbox API key. Here is the documentation page.
